# Excel:VBA code to Loop through combo box list and generate PDF for each.

Tags: vba, excel, xlsx, xlsm

I'm trying to create VBA code that selects each name one by one in a ComboBox on my worksheet. The linked Cell to the ComboBox is "D5"(which are employee names). However the ComboBox range where the names(about 1700 names) are located is on another worksheet in my workbook named "Sheet1" in column C.

When selecting a name from the ComboBox it appears in the link cell "D5". The value in "D5" is then used by other cells on the worksheet and creates a summary for the name selected. I need a macro that will select each name one by one from the ComboBox and save as a PDF.

What is a VBA Code that I can use that will loop through each name and save as PDF, as the name selected from the ComboBox into this folder C:\Users\SM\Desktop\ScorecardPDF ?

Comment: There is no ready-to-use VBA code for that. You will have to write one on your own. Try it and if you get errors or get stuck come back here with your code and a detailed question to it. Reading [ask] and [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) might help to improve your question.

Comment: My advice is, don't focus on the combo box, focus on the source range, i.e. "for each cl in sheet1.rng (blah blah).  Then take the data from the source range and drop it in D5, rinse and repeat.

Comment: That worked Perfectly. I was so caught up on trying do it through the comboBox list. I changed it to the source range and it worked like magic!

Answer (score 1):

This is my final code. For those who are experiencing the same issue.

```
Sub pdfProduce()
Dim rngLoopRange As Range
Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
Dim rngDealers As Worksheet

Set wsSummary = Sheets("Summary")

For Each rngLoopRange In Worksheets("owssvr").Range("$B$2:$B$1648")
  wsSummary.Range("D5").Value = rngLoopRange.Value

  wsSummary.ExportAsFixedFormat _
           Type:=xlTypePDF, _
           Filename:="C:\Users\S\Desktop\ScorecardPDF\" & rngLoopRange.Value & ".pdf", _
           Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
           IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
           IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
           OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next rngLoopRange

Set wsSummary = Nothing
End Sub
```